# @Specializes and JNDI in Java EE CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, jndi, cdi

In a Java EE 6.0 project we have a lot of beans under test. To get some additional information and to place additional test probes we make use of CDI's @Specializes annotation which works quite well. Beans with @Specializes annotation replace their parent class beans.

For example we have the two beans:

```
@Stateless    
public class Bean extends ... {}

@Specializes
public class BeanMock extends Bean {}
```

For normal injections this works very well. A

```
@Inject
private Bean bean;
```

brings a BeanMock to bean.

In one test we access a bean called "Bean" via JNDI. This test brings the exception:

```
14:29:07,867 ERROR [fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX.ear".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000047 Specializing bean must extend another bean:  Managed Bean [class xxx.BeanMock] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000047 Specializing bean must extend another bean:  Managed Bean [class xxx.BeanMock] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.preSpecialize(ManagedBean.java:449)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractBean.initialize(AbstractBean.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.initialize(AbstractClassBean.java:196)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.initialize(ManagedBean.java:322)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.AbstractBeanDeployer.deploy(AbstractBeanDeployer.java:115)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.deployBeans(BeanDeployment.java:204)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:344)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
    ... 5 more
```

I would like to get "BeanMock" via JNDI, if this is possible. ;-)

What is the defined behavior in that case. I already had a look into the JSR299, but did not find what happens for @Specializes beans via JNDI. Are they replaced, too?

Comment: Seems like it's because you're using EJBs here and your BeanMock isn't an EJB.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The Stateless bean annotation is inherited to the mock, I think. At least in the other cases I wrote about. I did not put another Stateless annotation to the classes and it works via normal Inject. I can give it a try tomorrow and check if another Stateless annotation makes a difference.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: No, never found a solution for that directly. What we did is, we provided an own CDI provider implementation to provide special mock classes for classes where an implementation with an own @Mock annotation for a certain interface existed. During the scan of the CDI we exchanged these implementations. For our tests a JNDI lookup was not needed anymore and we worked around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to scope your ejb with one of CDI scopes (application,session, request), or at least add @Named annotation, to see if it will then be seen as a CDI bean.